# updating multiple modules of an application with a single wsadmin script

Tags: java, bash, websphere, wsadmin

Environment AIX, websphere6.1

I am trying to update an existing java application using wsadmin script. I am able to update the application if i am updating single module(abc.war) of an application(xyz.ear) by using the following command

```
    AdminApp.update('xyz', 'modulefile', '[-operation addupdate -contents abc.war -contenturi abc.war -nodeployejb -BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding [["Increment EJB module"  Increment Increment.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml Inc]]]')
```

Is it possible to update multiple modules with a single wsadmin command? for example is it possible to update abc.war and abcdef.war of the same application with a single wsadmin command?

i am able to update the application from dmgr perfectly by zipping abc.war and abcdef.war into single zip file. I enabled command assistance logs and it was not writing anything when i update the application using the zip file and the option "Replace, add, or delete multiple files".

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. first list all the modules of that application and put in for loop to update them.

```
print AdminApp.listModules('DefaultApplication', '-server')
```

Here is the example.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_listmodule.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I don't want to use a python script or something else. Just want to use single wsadmin script for multiple modules. Also, my application contains 98 modules, of which i would like to update only 2 modules.